# Show progress of file upload PostAsync() in C# Android

Tags: c#, android, upload, http-post, httpclient

I have created a simple Android application which uploads recorded video files to my web server (PC), this works withs large and small files all good. The issue I am having is finding the current WORKING solution for showing some sort of progress of the file being uploaded.
I have searched stackoverflow already but only found two examples that seem to show success which are very old threads and all have later comments stating these solutions no longer work :(

Below is my code

```
private void Take_Video_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
            {
                await TakeVideoAsync(sender, e);

                videoView.Source = MediaSource.FromFile(VideoPath);

                byte[] imageBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(VideoPath);
                /*var base64image = System.Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
                base64image = "data:video/mp4;base64," + base64image;*/

                // Create an HTTP web request using the URL:
                var jn = JobNo.Text.ToString();
                var url = serverurl + "api/Data/uploadimage/" + JobNo.Text + "/1";

                try {
                    using (var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler())
                    {
                        httpClientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, cert, chain, errors) => { return true; };
                        using (var Client = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler))
                        {
                            Client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15);
                            DateTime currentDateTime = DateTime.Now;
                            string formattedDateTime = currentDateTime.ToString("ddMMyy_HHmmss");
                            var form = new MultipartFormDataContent();
                            ByteArrayContent byteContent = new ByteArrayContent(imageBytes);
                            var fileName = ("VID_JOB" + JobNo.Text + "_" + formattedDateTime + ".mp4");
                            form.Add(byteContent, "videofile", fileName);
                            App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Uploading Video", "Uploading recorded video, please wait for upload completion message!", "Close");
                            var response = await Client.PostAsync(url, form);
                            App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Upload Complete", "Upload Complete - " + fileName, "OK");
                            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Upload Failed", "Error code: " + ex.Message, "OK");
                }
            });

        }
```

Comment: any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Still struggling stackoverflow solutions don't work